# Updating exact value of column containing multiple values by using only one row with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php

How do I update an exact value of column containing multiple values by using only one row in PHP and MySQL?

Select:
KPL: "1,2,3,4"

Update and deletes old value:
KPL: "1,2,3,5"

Not like this:
KPL: "$_POST["kpl"]"

This is my current code, which does like this: KPL: "1,2,3,4,5"

```
$kpl=$_POST["kpl"];
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$bquery = mysql_query("SELECT kpl FROM table WHERE user='$user' AND date='$today'");
$bresult = mysql_fetch_array($bquery);
$b = $bresult[0];

$data = array();
foreach (explode(",", $b) as $i => $x) {
$data[$i]["kpl"] = $x;
if($data["kpl"] == $id) {
$exact = TRUE;
}
}

foreach ($data as $rivi) {
$kpl2 = $rivi["kpl"];

if(!(empty($kpl))) {
if($elintarvikeonkaytossa == TRUE) {
$b2 = sanitize($b.",".$kpl);
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET kpl='$b2' WHERE user='$user' AND date='$today'") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. How do I update the column and delete the old value?

Answer (score 0):

You must redesign your db because it's not compliant with [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), i.e. a single field can't handle more than a single value - we'd be using CSV or txt instead.

Long story short, instead of messing with sloppy php replace code, you should make a table with your `kpl` data, and store each number/id in a different row - this because your database should be *relational*, and not just a big repository of stuff.

Comment: I don't care about it if it's not security risk or doesn't slow down the system radically. Please, tell me is this even possible to do even though the current code works for different thing and what is CSV, is it just the way using another rows? I don't want to use another rows, because I want to proof myself that this is works. :D

Comment: I did not even go into security not performance, these are the very first elements of database design. This is not a place to get your stuff done, it's a place to share knowledge or to solve problems of common interest - start by using meaningful variables, commenting a bit your code and we'll give it a go maybe.